# IIS PHP error_log() logs in two timezones at the same time

Tags: php, windows, iis, logging

```php
error_log('AAA');
error_log('BBB');
```

results in:

```
[19-Aug-2016 09:29:36 UTC] AAA
[19-Aug-2016 09:29:36 UTC] BBB
[19-Aug-2016 10:29:36 Europe/London] AAA
[19-Aug-2016 10:29:36 Europe/London] BBB
```

This seems superfluous and is making the logs harder to read.

Any ideas why this is happening, and how to stop it?

Comment: Did you set a `date.timezone` in your PHP php.ini configuration? And is there another declaration somewhere in your PHP scripts?

Comment: That appears to be it - not every script does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the timezone is set in the script there will be logs for each timezone ever set.